# Matching parts of strings in SQL Server 2008 and also grouping them?

Tags: sql-server

I have data for an ID and for an associated concatenated string. I want to find instances in which at least one of the portions of the concatenated string matches with another grouped on the ID. Please see examples below for clarification:

This is the raw data as I currently have it (**note that the 'Row' column is only for explanatory reference**):

```
Row | ID | Concatenated Key
============================
  1    1      AAA_BBB
  2    1      AAA_BBB_CCC
  3    1      BBB_GGG_III
  4    1      DDD_HHH
  5    1      HHH_MMM
  6    1      FFF_GGG_III
  7    2      NNN_OOO
  8    2      NNN_PPP_RRR
  9    2      QQQ_SSS
  10   2      TTT_UUU
```

Notice how for each Key = {1,2} there are associated concatenated strings. I want to create groups in which *at least one* of the strings matches with another (overlaps). Here is an example of how I want my resulting data to look like:

```
Row | ID | Concatenated Key | Group
===================================
  1    1      AAA_BBB          1A
  2    1      AAA_BBB_CCC      1A
  3    1      BBB_GGG_III      1A
  4    1      DDD_HHH          1B
  5    1      HHH_MMM          1B
  6    1      FFF_GGG_III      1A
  7    2      NNN_OOO          2A
  8    2      NNN_PPP_RRR      2A
  9    2      QQQ_SSS          2B
  10   2      TTT_UUU          2C
```

Here are how the groups are defined based on which keys they include:

```
  1A: AAA, BBB, CCC, FFF, GGG, III
  1B: DDD, HHH, MMM
  2A: NNN, OOO, RRR
  2B: QQQ, SSS
  2C: TTT, UUU
```

As an example, take ID 2: For Row 7 and Row 8, NNN is shared and so they are in the same bucket. For Rows 9 and 10, none of them are shared with any other rows so they are in their own buckets. If any single string is shared with any another row, then they are all bucketed together.

Hope that this is a clear explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Ouch what a nightmarish bunch of denormalized data you have to deal with. You will have to first parse the delimited data, then you will need a recursive cte followed by the STUFF FOR XML trick to turn this back into denormalized data for output. Why can't the data be normalized? What you have is a horrible design forcing very painful and ugly sql so you can get results in a different yet still horrible design.

Comment: Looks like simple string parsing and comparison.   What part of it do you not know how to do?   Are you familiar with the PATINDEX and SUBSTRING functions in SQL?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have used STUFF FOR XML in the past but only through copy/paste as opposed to real understanding (did the job!). I am not familiar with PATINDEX unfortunately, but SUBSTRING is pretty straightforward. I know how to match across rows, but this also requires matching across entire columns (hence the recursive aspect as mentioned).

Comment: How are you going to handle data that belongs in two groups? Say for example if you had another row where ID = 1 and the key is 'GGG_HHH'

Comment: For the question, the strings are unique to the group. They are actually long combinations of numbers and alphanumeric characters, but I have simplified them here. In other words, every string is unique to an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the old fashion way. Iterate through data. 
It actually output your expected result sorted by group. So only the order is different.

It use '_' character to split the string and look for similar string.
Thus split function is required and included in the solution. Notice I added some logic into it for the operator "LIKE", so using a regular split function won't do unless you edit the codeé

```
IF object_id(N'SplitThatAddPercentCharacter', N'TF') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION SplitThatAddPercentCharacter
GO
CREATE FUNCTION SplitThatAddPercentCharacter
(    
    --Took from http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-function-in-SQL-Server-Example-Function-to-Split-Comma-separated-Delimited-string-in-SQL-Server-2005-2008-and-2012.aspx
    --Added the adding of "%" character.
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE 
(
      Item NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT '%' + SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1) + '%'

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END

GO

DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(   ID              INT,
                            ConcatenatedKey NVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @LoopingTable TABLE(    [Row]           INT,
                                ID              INT,
                                ConcatenatedKey NVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @Result TABLE(  ID              INT,
                        ConcatenatedKey NVARCHAR(MAX),
                        [Group]         NVARCHAR(2))


INSERT INTO @YourTable
VALUES
(1,      'AAA_BBB'),
(1,      'AAA_BBB_CCC'),
(1,      'BBB_GGG_III'),
(1,      'DDD_HHH'),
(1,      'HHH_MMM'),
(1,      'FFF_GGG_III'),
(2,      'NNN_OOO'),
(2,      'NNN_PPP_RRR'),
(2,      'QQQ_SSS'),
(2,      'TTT_UUU')


INSERT INTO @LoopingTable
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, ConcatenatedKey),
        ID,
        ConcatenatedKey
FROM @YourTable
--ORDER BY ID, ConcatenatedKey

DECLARE @RowIterator                    INT,
        @idFromPreviousIteration        INT,
        @idIterator                     INT,
        @ConcatenatedKeyIterator        NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @GroupValueForCurrentIteration  NVARCHAR(2),
        @GroupIncrementASCIICode        INT

SELECT @idFromPreviousIteration  = -1

WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @LoopingTable))
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1    @RowIterator                    = [Row],
                    @idIterator                     = ID,
                    @ConcatenatedKeyIterator        = ConcatenatedKey,
                    @GroupValueForCurrentIteration  = NULL
    FROM @LoopingTable

    IF(@idIterator <> @idFromPreviousIteration)
    BEGIN       
        SELECT  @GroupIncrementASCIICode        = 65,--A
                @GroupValueForCurrentIteration  = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @idIterator) + CHAR(@GroupIncrementASCIICode)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 @GroupValueForCurrentIteration = [Group]
        FROM @Result
        INNER JOIN dbo.Split(@ConcatenatedKeyIterator, '_') AS KeySplitted ON ConcatenatedKey LIKE Item

        IF(@GroupValueForCurrentIteration IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @GroupIncrementASCIICode        = @GroupIncrementASCIICode + 1,--Increment letter
                    @GroupValueForCurrentIteration  = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @idIterator) + CHAR(@GroupIncrementASCIICode)
        END
    END

    INSERT INTO @Result
    VALUES(@idIterator, @ConcatenatedKeyIterator, @GroupValueForCurrentIteration)

    SELECT @idFromPreviousIteration = @idIterator

    DELETE @LoopingTable
    WHERE [Row] = @RowIterator

END

SELECT  [Row] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Group]),
        ID,
        ConcatenatedKey,
        [Group]
FROM @Result
```